# mysql query to replace links inside text: can this be done?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to write a MySQL query to replace links inside an HTML hypertext link as follows:

ex:

```
hello world <a href="http://www.sample.com/">hello world2</a>
hello world2 <a href="http://www.sample.com/news.php">hello world2</a>
```

and turns this into:

```
hello world <a href="http://www.sample.com/?kid=1000">hello world2</a>
hello world <a href="http://www.sample.com/news.php?kid=1000">hello world2</a>
```

(basically adding an extra parameter to all links starting with `http://www.sample.com`)

Comment: [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) say `REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)` function should work

Comment: No beacuse it should ADD to the END of the string and urls can be VARIOUS !

Comment: Well, you could search for http: then find the position of the first " after http and substitute the " with your appended value.

Comment: Could multiple http:// links be in a single text block?  if so then I think the answer is not without a UDF for a regexreplace.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql  (trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel here)

Comment: maybe by using regexp to dynamically "URL" then use replace? but this would have to be done in a loop if multiple urls per record.